# Possible to create web app without a framework?

Tags: php, html, css, web-applications

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a web application where a user can sign up,login, and make payments without using a framework like Rails or Node.js, but rather html,css,php,mysql etc.
Is this even possible?

Comment: I will flag this question as "too broad" because it is not a concrete question concerning programming. But the short answer is "yes" - simply because frameworks are based on other techniques like html, css, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will take a lot of time but it sure is possible. These 'frameworks' are here to speed things up for you. I recommend you to take a look at a couple of MVC frameworks. For example: [Laravel](https://laravel.com/), [Codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com/) and [Symfony](https://symfony.com/). These frameworks will do a lot for you(Think about security and routing) but you still have to write the biggest part of the logic yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is entirely possible to write any web application without framework. Keep in mind that frameworks are also written in their respective programming languages - therefore, you can achieve same results without one, but it will be more time-consuming and will need more work to "reinvent the wheel". A framework usually delivers many useful functionalities that are ready to use, but in the exchange you must comply to its standards, semantics and rules.

Many programmers of high-end applications choose to develop without a framework, because they don't want to be bound by those boundaries. Also, there are performance reasons - if you can fine tailor your application to your business requirements, it will probably run faster.

Also, please keep in mind that Node.js isn't a framework - it is a toolset that allows running JavaScript applications in OS enviroment instead of the browser.